# Number of array accesses seems wrong

Tags: arrays, algorithm

If I were to run this code:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    for j in range(0, 5):
        for k in range(0, 5):
            count = count + 1
            print(count)
```

I would get the expected answer, `125`, or `N^3`. So how is the following picture (N^3)/6. I understand the formula for mathematical sums but the code in the very inner for loop is getting executed N^3 times no? Wouldn't that make the code in the picture have N^3 array accesses?

[d http://www.domfarolino.com/q.JPG](http://www.domfarolino.com/q.JPG)

### Edit:

Yes I see how the code in the picture is comparing total steps with a given value as opposed to the O notation, sorry for getting these mixed up.

Comment: Nothing to do with complexity analysis, changed the title.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference, O(n^3) is exactly the same as O((n^3)/2). The big O notation ignores constant factors.

If you are looking for exact number of steps, the two code snippets are different, and both derivations are correct for their respective snippet.

Comment: Question title is misleading, but OP obviously asks for number of steps.

Answer (score 2):

You've translated the code incorrectly. The two inner loops don't run from 0 to N, they run starting at the current value of the loop containing them. For instance, when `i=0`, the second loop runs from 1 to N; when `j=1`, the third loop runs from 2 to N. A more appropriate translation of this code would be:

```
for i in range(0, N):
    for j in range(i, N):
        for k in range(j, N):
            count = count + 3
```

That being said, as others have mentioned, big-O notation does not take constant factors into account. `O(n^3 / 2)` is the same as `O(n^3)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is O(N^3). Please read up on O notation as it only describes the expansion.